# Variant, Recursive Function and Type Inference

Tags: recursion, ocaml, type-inference, variant

I'm very new at OCaml but worked all the past two days in order to get a good understanding of how to use it.
I've been doing a lot of thing lately but something is keeping me from moving forward.

I'm trying to implement an evalexpr in OCaml. Pretty easy using this langage you would say : so I thought, and the first I did, using regular ints, worked fine.
But now I'm trying to do so using my OWN type and my own functions to solve operations : and of course it's not as easy as I expected.

```
type expr =
  | Number of MyInt.myint
  | Sum of (expr * expr)
  | Sub of (expr * expr)
  | Product of (expr * expr)
  | Divide of (expr * expr)
  | Modulo of (expr * expr)

let rec evalexpr expr = function
  | Number n       -> n
  | Sum (a, b)     -> MyInt.add (evalexpr a) (evalexpr b)
  | Sub (a, b)     -> MyInt.sub (evalexpr a) (evalexpr b)
  | Product (a, b) -> MyInt.mul (evalexpr a) (evalexpr b)
  | Divide (a, b)  -> MyInt.div (evalexpr a) (evalexpr b)
  | Modulo (a, b)  -> MyInt.modulo (evalexpr a) (evalexpr b)
```

This seems ok to me... but the compiler disagrees.
I think it's pretty obvious that the "(evalexpr a)" is of type MyInt.myint, as it is the only final return value the evalexpr function can return : still, the compiler think its type is "expr -> MyInt.myint".

Does it means it doesn't apply the function evalexpr and returns the function itself ?? if so, why the hell would it do that ?
I just can't figure it out. And I can't think of another way to do what I'm trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove `expr` from your `evalexpr` function.

```
let rec evalexpr = function
    ...
```

By having it there, you are declaring that the function takes 2 paramemters.  The first will be bound to the variable `expr` and the second will be matched in the function body.  Then when you try to recursively call it, you call `evalexpr` with single parameters yielding functions expecting the second parameter.  Then naturally your functions cannot operate on functions hence the error.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think it should be like this:

```
let rec evalexpr = function
  | Number n       -> n
  | Sum (a, b)     -> MyInt.add (evalexpr a) (evalexpr b)
  | Sub (a, b)     -> MyInt.sub (evalexpr a) (evalexpr b)
  | Product (a, b) -> MyInt.mul (evalexpr a) (evalexpr b)
  | Divide (a, b)  -> MyInt.div (evalexpr a) (evalexpr b)
  | Modulo (a, b)  -> MyInt.modulo (evalexpr a) (evalexpr b)
```

function statement already takes an argument for you so what you actually declared was a function that takes one argument and returns a function